# videoView.setOnPreparedListener, videoView.setOnCompletionListener and videoView.setOnErrorListener not getting called

Tags: android, android-videoview, listeners

Here is my code snippet where I want to play a video coming from server

```
private void PlayVideo() {
    try {
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoPlayer.removeAllViews();
        videoPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                dismissProgressDialog();
                videoView.bringToFront();
                videoView.setFocusable(true);
                videoView.start();
                contentStarted = true;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                contentStarted = false;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                dismissProgressDialog();
                Intent in = new Intent();
                setResult(1, in);
                finish();
                return false;
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        finish();
    }
}
```

The `ProgressDialog` is dismissed only in `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` and `videoView.setOnErrorListener`. But the `ProgressDialog` is not getting dismissed and video is not getting played. I tried to put Logs and see, Logs are printed upto just before `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` and after that no Logs are displayed. `Listeners` are not getting registered I guess.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

'M trying to stream a live video, if video is availbale it should go to `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` and should play the video. If Live is not available(i.e, Video will be live after some time) then it should go to `videoView.setOnErrorListener` and return to previous `Activity` with result "1"

and

Video is streamed over `RTSP`

Comment: videoPlayer.removeAllViews(); for what ?

Comment: I'M having an alternative videoplayer(for ads) which I'M removing so that only the videoView to play live video is present

Comment: I think you should call videoView.prepare();

Comment: You are sure the path of the video you have provided is exist ?

Comment: There is no prepare() for the type VideoView

Comment: 'M trying to stream a live video, if video is availbale it should go to `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` and should play the video. If Live is not available(i.e, Video will be live after some time) then it should go to `videoView.setOnErrorListener` and return to previous `Activity` with result "1"

Comment: what happened? it worked ?

Comment: The fault was in the URL. If user want to watch a video at 3PM which will be Live at 6PM the Listeners are not getting attached to Video View. But if user watches at 6PM Live video is playing. So I changed Logic to make the video Buffer only if Present Time is same as Live Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research and with the help of  Preethi Rao I got to know that the fault was in the `URL`.

The `URL` might have the video (if it is time for Live Video) and might not have video (if Live Video will be streaming after some time). If I'm trying to stream video when Live Video is not available then the `Listeners` are not getting fired. If Live Video is availbale, `Listeners` are getting fired. So, `videoView.setOnPreparedListener` and `videoView.setOnErrorListener` are not getting attached.

I wrote a handler to run for 60 seconds and if no `Listeners` are attached I'm just returning to previous `Activity`.

Here's the code:

```
private void PlayVideo() {
    try {
        isListenerAttached = false;
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoPlayer.removeAllViews();
        videoPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Using this Handler to revert to previous Activity when the Video View is not attached to Listeners
        // As the Buffering Video dialog doesn't get dismissed if Video View is not attached to Listeners
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!isListenerAttached){
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                            Intent in = new Intent();
                            setResult(1, in);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }, WAIT_TIME);
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                isListenerAttached = true;
                dismissProgressDialog();
                videoView.bringToFront();
                videoView.setFocusable(true);
                videoView.start();
                contentStarted = true;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                contentStarted = false;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                isListenerAttached = true;
                dismissProgressDialog();
                Intent in = new Intent();
                setResult(1, in);
                finish();
                return false;
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        dismissProgressDialog();
        finish();
    }
}
```